# Modify Cache Headers On Scrapy ImagesPipeline

Tags: python, scrapy

By default Scrapy is setting 2 days (172800 seconds) `Cache-Control` headers on all images saved with `ImagesPipeline`. I want to update this value to 2592000, or 30 days.

The original ImagesPipeline looks like this:

```
class ImagesPipeline(FilesPipeline):
    ...
    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        ...
        s3store = cls.STORE_SCHEMES['s3']
        ...
...
```

In inherits from FilesPipeline which defines `STORE_SCHEMES`

```
class FilesPipeline(MediaPipeline):
    ...
    STORE_SCHEMES = {
        '': FSFilesStore,
        'file': FSFilesStore,
        's3': S3FilesStore,
    }
    ...
```

S3FilesStore looks like this:

```
class S3FilesStore(object):
    ...
    POLICY = 'public-read'
    HEADERS = {
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=172800',
    }
```

I tested just editing the original value in the original scrapy class and change it from 172800 to 2592000. That works fine and the cache becomes 30 days on all images when I test it. But obviously that is not a good solution, I want to override it with my custom class.

So, to be able to override the `S3FilesStore` `HEADERS = {}`, I have to create a custom class that I call `CustomS3FilesStore` that overrides the variable, and then create a custom ImagesPipeline that set `CustomS3FilesStore` as `s3store`.

I do this with the following code:

```
# Override the default headers and policies with a 30 days cache
class CustomS3FilesStore(S3FilesStore):
    POLICY = 'public-read'
    HEADERS = {
        'Cache-Control': 'max-age=2592000',
    }

# Set S3 scheme to our own override class CustomS3FilesStore
class CustomImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    @classmethod
    def from_settings(cls, settings):
        cls.MIN_WIDTH = settings.getint('IMAGES_MIN_WIDTH', 0)
        cls.MIN_HEIGHT = settings.getint('IMAGES_MIN_HEIGHT', 0)
        cls.EXPIRES = settings.getint('IMAGES_EXPIRES', 90)
        cls.THUMBS = settings.get('IMAGES_THUMBS', {})

        # Override the default value to our CustomS3FilesStore Class
        s3store = CustomS3FilesStore
        s3store.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = settings['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID']
        s3store.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = settings['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']

        cls.IMAGES_URLS_FIELD = settings.get('IMAGES_URLS_FIELD', cls.DEFAULT_IMAGES_URLS_FIELD)
        cls.IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD = settings.get('IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD', cls.DEFAULT_IMAGES_RESULT_FIELD)
        store_uri = settings['IMAGES_STORE']
        return cls(store_uri)
```

I then use my CustomImagesPipeline in my settings.py file in `ITEM_PIPELINES` like this:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'condobot.pipelines.CustomImagesPipeline': 100,
    ...
}
```

Result: When I run the crawler I run into 0 errors, and all images are downloaded. But the cache headers of the images are still only 2 days, or 172800 seconds. I was not successful in overriding the setting.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? How do I actually change the Cache-Control of Scrapy Images?

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong with the code. Does it help to set the CustomImagesPipeline to 1 instead of 100? Can you update the code with the correct imports, just to make sure everything is referenced right?

Comment: Obviously the Pipeline is running, since it IS downloading images and saving them correctly.

Comment: I wasn't questioning whether the pipeline is running.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're not really overriding the default value for `S3FilesStore`.

The `*FilesStore` classes are registered in the [`STORE_SCHEMES`](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/pipelines/files.py#L148) attribute -- in the `from_settings` it's just used to get the AWS keys.

Try setting it in the constructor, like this:

```
class CustomImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomImagesPipeline, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.STORE_SCHEMES['s3'] = CustomS3FilesStore

    ...
```

Comment: This just saved me after a few hours of googling. The only difference for me was having to it in the following order
`self.STORE_SCHEMES = FilesPipeline.STORE_SCHEMES`
`self.STORE_SCHEMES['gs'] = AuthedGSFilesStore`
`super(CustomPipeline, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`